# Shall I use an article before "Smoldering fire"

Tags: articles

I'm writing this sentence:

> I'm almost sure this is smoldering fire.

and I don't put an article before smoldering. But, when I say **friendly fire** or **camp fire** then I would normally like to add an article before them, and write **This is the a friendly fire, or this is a camp fire**, and know I'm not sure whether I need to put an article before **smoldering fire** too!

> I'm almost sure this is **a** smoldering fire.

Comment: It depends whether you mean **a fire** in the sense of a heap of fuel deliberately set alight, or **fire** meaning the action of burning. (**Fire** can also mean shooting - **friendly fire** has come to mean 'shots fired by one's own side in a conflict'.)

Comment: @KateBunting I mean it is the lull before the storm.

Comment: Then you don't need an article.

Comment: I personally would definitely use the article, since the metaphor contemplates that the particular situation is an individual fire, just as I would say: "This is a mess/a disaster/an accident waiting to happen/etc."  :"Friendly fire," however, is a generic reference to the type of event.  To refer to a specific event, you would preferably say something like: "This is a case of friendly fire."

Comment: @Vegawatcher , Kate is right. it doesn't need an article, because I don't refer to the "fire" itself. what I'm implying to, is the "calm before the storm", and it doesn't need an article

Comment: @BM of Spadana: But the expression "the calm before the storm" again uses an article.  You would not say "*this situation is like calm before the storm" without using an article.  I still don't understand.  I do understand how one could technically say: "This is smoldering fire," but the usage sounds quite unusual to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you're describing the physical fire, or defining/comparing a *type* of fire. For example:

- Inside *that* bale is a smoldering fire.
- As compared to the conflagration of a fluffy cotton ball, inside a cotton bale, there is little air, so that causes smoldering fire.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you want "fire" to be a mass noun or count noun:

> Smoldering fire, when it is not extinguished, causes many forest fires.
> A smoldering fire, when it is not extinguished, can cause a forest fire.

The first sentence describes smoldering fire in general. The second refers to a single smoldering fire.

"Friendly fire" is generally a mass noun (and thus should **not** have an indefinite article), and "camp fire" is generally a count noun.